# Laravel выборка

Tags: laravel

Делаю выборку в контроллере и вывожу в формате Json!

```
$events = $this->db->select('name', 'rid', 'class')->where('md2', 'sad7a6d6a5d6s5ad6a5sasd56')->get()->toArray();
 echo (json_encode($events));
```

Таким образом выводятся все элементы, что соответствуют условию.
Как в самом контроллере сделать, чтобы поле class каждой выбранной записи проверялось на условие? Переборка в цикле или ещё что-то. Какой вариант на Ваш взгляд удобнее? Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter) для коллекции, вот так:

```
$events = $this->db->select('name', 'rid', 'class')->where('md2', 'sad7a6d6a5d6s5ad6a5sasd56')->get();

$filtered = $events->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value->class == true; //Здесь пишите свое условие
});

$result = $filtered->all()->toArray();

echo (json_encode($result));
```

UPD. вам больше подойдет метод [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map):

```
<?php

$events = $this->db->select('name', 'rid', 'class')->where('md2', 'sad7a6d6a5d6s5ad6a5sasd56')->get()->toArray();

$multiplied = $events->map(function ($value) {
    if ($value['class'] > 0) {
        $value['data_from_db'] = \DB::table('table')->first();
    }
    return $value;
});

$result = $multiplied->all();

echo (json_encode($result));
```

Comment: Я так понял, что в таком случае будут сохраняться элементы, которые соответствуют условию. Где-то тоже может пригодится. В моём случае же, необходимо проверить, что class > 0, сделать дополнительный запрос к б.д. и ответ этого запроса добавить, новым элементом массива к ранее полученному построчно ответу $events. Как-то так

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов вам нужно добавить в ответ к name, rid, class новой колонкой?

Comment: Да. Всё правильно!

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов а остальные оставить как есть или убрать с массива?

Comment: Коллекции, что не соответствуют условию, должны проходить дальше без корректив. Где условие истинно, остальные оставляются + новый элемент к ним...

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов обновил ответ